# Жирный желтый текст в блоке кода discord

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Хотел задать вопрос по discord'у. Закреплен скрин из моего лс, где видно, что бот пишет *желтым жирным текстом в блоке кода*. Нигде не могу найти, как это сделать и можно ли сделать с помощью библиотеки discord.py или же просто на **python**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Должно быть как-то так

```
**

\`\`\`
fix

test

``\`

**
```

[image: Пример]

В итоге получиться так

[image]

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)))))

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы изменить текст сообщения в дискорде (в том числе на желтый) используйте данную конструкцию:

````
```
текст сообщения
```
````

(По умолчанию меняется на красный)

Для желтого цвета:

````
```fix
текст сообщения
```
````

Подробнее можете прочитать [здесь](https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/8lev3t/discord_colored_text_with_code_markup_guide/).

Чтобы писать жирным шрифтом:

```
**текст сообщения**
```

Соответственно, чтобы писать желтым жирным шрифтом, надо совместить предыдущие две конструкции:

````
**
```fix
текст сообщения
```
**
````

Как итог получаем:

[image: Вывод]

Comment: Я знаю про этот метод, но мне нужен именно **жирный** желтый цвет текста...

Comment: Как на скрине в вопросе

Comment: Это вроде как и есть жирный текст, сравните текст со звездочками и без.

Comment: Нет, в блоке кода звёздочки не работают(

Comment: Простите, а как можно укоротить черную полосу выделения, чтобы выделялось только сообщение?